# I accidently send unrequited Token to Pancakeswap Pool. My Tokens liquidity stolen

Tags: contract-development, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I am an owner of bep20 token and locked the liquidity with mudra locker. I accidentally send token from outside to pancakeswap pair address and 2k dolar WBNB transferred to an unknown wallet.  My ınvestors funds are gone. I need help as soon as possible.
This is my cert by mudra locker. https://mudra.website/?certificate=yes&type=0&lp=0x52b3d84f29cd935fe7bcb573dd2de63c6d39c5ee
This is unknown wallet my liquidity WBNB send with this transaction https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbeb4d6214f5a654dcc4f5a34f34c0e9ba4e3b184bfbadaf6246ef73a22e3de8b

This is my Critical failure send Token to pair address
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xabac560acda447f9466ad548adab5992940d7f79d1b4adf3b11d9d5d96ef3ede

Answer (score 0):

https://bscscan.com/tx/0xabac560acda447f9466ad548adab5992940d7f79d1b4adf3b11d9d5d96ef3ede well this tx happened on the same block as this one https://bscscan.com/tx/0xbeb4d6214f5a654dcc4f5a34f34c0e9ba4e3b184bfbadaf6246ef73a22e3de8b. My guess (im not super familiar with uniswap contracts) is that somehow the attacker found a way to make the contract believe that he was the one who sent the APT tokens (theres a `swap` event in the logs of the second transaction, and amount1In roughly correspond to the amount of APT tokens you sent in the first transaction). Since both transactions happened at the same time, i think the usual check in the `swap` function failed somehow and believed that it should send an amount of BNB to the attacker corresponding to the amount of APT you sent to the contract (maybe someone that knows uniswap contract better than me can explain it in more detail) (also english isnt my first language, i apologise if any of this isnt clear ^^')